# Expressing dependencies for modules removed from Java 11 in Gradle published metadata

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

I have a library that uses JAXB, which has been removed from Java 11. My library must be compatible with both Java 8 and Java 11.
Building & testing the library is easy enough, as I add the following dependency if a Java 11 runtime is detected during the build:

```
implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.3"
```

However, my goal is to publish metadata with two variants, one with attribute org.gradle.jvm.version set to 8 without the JAXB dependency, and one with attribute org.gradle.jvm.version set to 11 and the JAXB dependency.
I’d also like for this to be transparent to the consumer, i.e. that its dependency declaration remains

```
implementation "foo:bar:1.0.0"
```

Is this possible with the current version of Gradle? By declaring a variant of the default capability?

Comment: I suggest cross-referencing yourself: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/expressing-optional-java-11-dependencies-in-published-metadata/36504

Comment: Did you manage to come up with something? I’m facing the exact same problem and I’ve tried both here and on the gradle forum yet I can't find an answer to this.

Comment: @johny.bravo Unfortunately no. I haven't had time since to experiment further, but this looks like a use-case that is going to be more and more common.